# MongoDB C# Driver Multiple Update

Tags: c#, mongodb

this code is working but, this is updating just one document. I want to update all same images.

```
UpdateBuilder updateBuilder = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update
.Set("isAdded", "true");
mongoCollection.Update(Query.EQ("image", "imgURL"), updateBuilder);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with this code.

```
        var update = new UpdateDocument
        {
            {"$set",new BsonDocument("isAdded","true") }
        };

        var query = new QueryDocument
        {
            {"image","imgUrl" }
        };

        mongoCollection.Update(query, update, new MongoUpdateOptions
        {
            Flags = UpdateFlags.Multi
        }
        );
```